# Wait for C# asynchronous function to finish executing in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, asynchronous, async-await

I have exposed some functions from my C# VSTO ribbon and I can call them with a VBA Excel button. One of these functions is an asynchronous function - its operations are placed on a separate thread so it does not lock Excel. I would like that when I click it, the button is disabled (cannot be clicked again) until the async function is completed. Is this possible with VBA, if so, how?

Here is an implementation of my code so far:

```
Sub myButton_Click()
   ' disable this button'
   Dim addIn As AddIn
   Dim automationObject As Object
   Set addIn = Application.AddIns("myAddIn")
   Set automationObject = addIn.Object

   automationObject.myAsyncFunc
   ' enable this button when myAsyncFunc finishes execution' 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use the Excel Application to your AddIn, then call the enable from the add in based on this info?

Comment: Idiomatic asynchronous VBA code would leverage events, but then events require early binding AFAIK. I'd look into exposing some `AsyncFuncCompleted` event on the C# side, and handling in on the VBA side using a `Private WithEvents automation As TheEventSourceClass` and `Private Sub TheEventSourceClass_AsyncFuncCompleted()` - if needed you could even pass data through the parameters.

Comment: Suggestion: expose an object property on the addin to make a clearer API and avoid polluting the add-in class with lower-level concerns that don't really belong there. e.g. `Set automation = addIn.AutomationAPI`

Comment: ugh that would be `Private Sub automation_AsyncFuncCompleted()`, mistyped that, too late to edit